# If $g$ is inverse function of $f$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$. Find $g'(x)$

Tags: functions

> **Problem** : If $g$ is inverse function of $f$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$. 
>   Find $g'(x)$ in terms of $g$
>
> **Solution**:
>
> $g= \frac {1}{f}$
>
> Differentiating we get
>
> $g'= \frac {1}{f'}$
>
> $g'= 1+x^3 $
>
> $g=x + \frac{x^4}{4}$

Am I doing right ??

Also Is $f(g(x))=x $ in this question ??

Comment: Are you sure the inverse in the question means taking reciprocal? Assume its true...then you made a mistake in differentiating g. Try to check your differentiation.

Comment: I also have doubts in my method

Comment: The inverse function means $g(f(x)) = x$.

Comment: The inverse of a function of $f$ does **not** usually refer to $\frac1f$.

Comment: If $g(f(x)) = x$, try differentiating both sides and apply the chain rule.

Comment: How can we prove $g(f(x))=x $ ??

Comment: You don't need to prove it, the problem tells you that it's true.  We are given that $g$ is the inverse function of $f$, and that's how you define an inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we define the inverse function $g(x)$ of $f(x)$ as the function such that for any $x$,
$$
f(g(x)) = x
$$
In order to do this problem, note that starting with the above equality, we can differentiate both sides (using the chain rule) to find
$$
f'(g(x))g'(x)=1
$$Solving for $g'(x)$, this becomes
$$
g'(x)=\frac1{f'(g(x))}
$$
How can we apply the above to this problem?

Comment: As $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ So $f'(g)=\frac{1}{1+g^3}$ Am I right ??

Comment: Not exactly.  $g'(x)$, which is what we're looking for, is equal to $\frac1{f'(g(x)}$.  That is, $g'(x) = \frac1{1+(g(x))^3}$

Comment: Then $g'(x)=1+ (g(x))^3$

Comment: Why do you say that?  How do you get that from my previous comment?

Comment: you got the result $$
g'(x)=\frac1{f'(g(x))}
$$ As $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3} so f'(g(x))=\frac{1}{1+(g(x))^3}$ using above result in your result we get $g'(x)= 1+(g(x))^3$

Comment: Oh I'm sorry you were totally correct.  I managed to misuse my own result.  Good job.